# Finding Ratio from Quadratic Equation?

Tags: physics, quadratics, mathematical-physics

[image]

In this question I encountered the quadratic equation Q1^2 + Q2^2 - 6(Q1)(Q2) = 0

How can I find the ration of Q1/Q2 ? How is the answer coming C please help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide your equation by $Q2^2$.  You will have a quadratic in $\frac {Q1}{Q2}$ which completing the square or the quadratic formula will solve.

Because of the symmetry of the problem some ratio for $\frac {Q1}{Q2}$ and its inverse must both be solutions because you can rename the two spheres and get the reciprocal ratio.  Only choice c gives two choices, so it has to be right.   You can verify $-(3+\sqrt 8)(-3+\sqrt 8)=1$ as a check.